# How to catch when a selector is passed to jQuery() that does not exist in document, to stop further possible errors or omissions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, runtime-error

Given

```js
$(function() {
  $(".planChoice").on("click", function() {
    console.log(123)
  });
  
  console.log($(".planChoice").length)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

jQuery happilly allows chaining `.on()` to `jQuery()` call where selector passed to `jQuery()` does not exist in `document`. Where `.addEventListener()` throws a `TypeError`

> `Cannot read property 'addEventListenet' of null`

```js
$(function() {
  document.querySelector(".planChoice")
  .addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(123)
  });
  
  console.log(document.querySelector(".planChoice").length)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

How can we adjust (improve) `jQuery()` to throw the same `TypeError` when the selector or element does not exist in `document` at the time `jQuery()` is called and, or a jQuery method is chained to the `jQuery()` call which returns a jQuery object - though no underlying element exists matching the selector string within `document` at the time of the call?

Comment: This **is** the improvement, jQuery fails silently when the element doesn't exist

Comment: @adeneo Not sure what you mean? Do you mean that the current implementation of [`jQuery()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery) to fail silently is by design of the jQuery authors and contributors, and considered as an "improvement"? We can use `.is()`, which an option, though am also interested in adjusting `jQuery()` function itself. The present Question stems from point mentioned by @brk at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639528/ajax-not-working-properly/45639591?noredirect=1#comment78238827_45639591

Comment: Yes, I mean that it's designed to fail silently if an element isn't found.

Comment: @adeneo Can you provide a link to that discussion at an issue or documentations?

Comment: I don't think there's much of a discussion, it's just a known. jQuery goes out of it's way to make sure that it's methods don't throw errors, and just fails silently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to throw an error, you can edit `jQuery()` / `$`

```js
$ = function (selector, context) {
    var el = new jQuery.fn.init(selector, context);
    if (el.length === 0) throw new Error('fail : "' + selector + '" Not Found');
    return el;
}

$('body'); // okay, returns element

$('nosuchthing'); // fail, throws error
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Another way would be to just return `null` or `undefined` instead of an empty collection, and let the next function chained on throw the error

```js
$ = function (selector, context) {
  var el = new jQuery.fn.init(selector, context);
    if (el.length === 0) return null;
    return el;
}

$('body').on('click', function() {}) // hunkydory
$('nosuchthing').on('click', function() {}) // can't read property "on" of "null"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *do* want the error to be thrown, just use the vanilla javascript instead of the jquery function.

Comment: Yes,  that is one option, though not the gist of the Question